# Programmatically add node translation drupal 7 ( Entity translation )

Tags: i18n-l10n

I need to create multilingual node programmatically in Drupal with entity_translation.

No problem to create the node, but I have no idea how can I create the translation ( + field translated).

I don't want to create another node, just translate it (same nid).

My language is FR , I need translation in EN and DE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer ! Thanks to my co worker.

In order to add translation to a node you need to add every translatable field like this in your creation node code :

```
 $node->field_trailer['fr'][0]['value'] = $movie['link'];  
 $node->field_trailer['de'][0]['value'] = $movie['link'];  
 $node->field_trailer['en'][0]['value'] = $movie['link'];
```

And after `node_save($node);` add

```
  node->translations->data['de']['entity_type'] = 'node'; 
  $node->translations->data['de']['entity_id'] = $node->nid;
  $node->translations->data['de']['language'] = 'de'; 
  $node->translations->data['de']['source'] = 'fr';   
  $node->translations->data['de']['uid'] = $node->uid;  
  $node->translations->data['de']['status'] = $node->status; 
  $node->translations->data['de']['translate'] = 0; 
  $node->translations->data['de']['created'] = $node->created; 
  $node->translations->data['de']['changed'] = $node->changed;
```

For each language and the `node_save($node)` again.

Comment: Works fine for terms as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is other solution. Perhaps you already have $node object (from node_load or menu_get_object etc), and $lang - langcode to translate:

```
$handler  = entity_translation_get_handler('node', $node);
$translations = $handler->getTranslations();
if ($lang !== $node->language && !isset($translations->data[$lang])) {
  $translation_node = $node;
  $values = array();
  // Change translatable fields languages to trasnlation language.
  foreach(field_info_instances('node', $node->type) as $instance) {
    $field_name = $instance['field_name'];
    $field = field_info_field($field_name);
    if ($field['translatable'] && isset($translation_node->$field_name)) {
      foreach ($translation_node->$field_name as $lang_key => $field) {
        if ($lang_key == $node->language) {
          $values[$field_name][$lang] = $field;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // Create a translation.
  $translation = array(
    'translate' => 0,
    'status' => 1,
    'language' => $lang,
    'source' => $node->language,
  );
  $handler->setTranslation($translation, $values);
  node_save($translation_node);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, after some fine tuning it worked for me. Just one thing: how to translate title of the node?

Comment: You should use https://www.drupal.org/project/title module