# How to get value of Textarea in node add form?

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

In my node add form I have added one text area :

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == "contenttype_node_form") {
         if (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) {
             $form['extra']['#title'] = t('Title (Extra)');
             $form['extra']['#type'] = 'textarea';
             $form['extra']['#required'] = TRUE;
             $form['extra']['#cols'] = '15';
             $form['extra']['#resizable'] = FALSE;
             $form['extra']['#rows'] = '5';

             $form['#submit'][] = 'my_trans_submit';

        }
    }
}


function my_trans_submit(&$form, &$form_state){
  $swed_title = $form['extra']['#value'];
}
```

Above code display one textarea just after title field in my node form. I Need the value entered in this text-area when user click on **save node** and then I want to use that value and save translation by running node save function. I can get this on form submit, but at that time node is not created and nid is not available.

How can I get value entered by the users in the above textarea once the node is saved and the node ID will be available, allowing me to use `node_save()`? Do I have to use a form field? I was not using a form field as it creates a new entity table.

Comment: save translation means? what exactly this field using for?

Comment: I need to run this code http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123460/programmatically-add-node-translation-drupal-7-entity-translation by using value entered in textarea.  By doing this user will save node and its translation at same time ie: in one node save click by user from from.

Comment: In my case I want to use that value `$node->field_title['fr'][0]['value'] = $from['extra']['value'];` but all other things are also required like nid etc so just need that value after node get saved.

Comment: I think I need to use hook_node_insert

Comment: As side note, a form submission handler gets the values the user entered from `$form_state['values']`, not from `$form`.

Comment: @espero  I can access with both ways like `$form_state['build_info']['args'][0]-> extra);`   and  `$form['extra']['#value']` whats the difference to use form state values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly put, you need to do the following:

- Use hook_form_alter, the way you do already
- Use [hook_node_submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7), to update the field_title field on the node object, before it gets saved. In your hook implementation you will have access to both $form and $form_state, which should carry your custom textarea submitted value. Even if the nid is not there, your changes should still get stored in the new node.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks but I need to add $node->translations->data in entity_translation table as well. By default this enter data related to default language when node gets created. So in hook_presave is that will be possible to add like http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123460/programmatically-add-node-translation-drupal-7-entity-translation.  Just asking for more clarification, please suggest ?

Comment: I updated my answer, I find that hook_node_submit is even better than hook_node_presave, see above. And yes, that code from the link you provide should make it possible to add translations to your entity (node).

Comment: Grand, happy to hear!